# Having trouble iterating through json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't iterate through this json

```
r = requests.get('https://www.artblocks.io/_next/data/2P2SW97nLmkSHj5AuF98r/artists.json')

data = r.json()

with open('test_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)


with open('test_data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for _ in data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data']:
    print(_)
```

this returns each character instead of the dict i'm trying to get

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
{
"
u
s
e
r
s
"
:
[
{
"
p
u
b
l
i
c
_
a
d
d
r
e
s
...
"
}
]
}
```

same with this:

```
print(data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data'])
```

gives me:

```
{"users":[{"public_address":"0x76a5e5202b097cf115494a20653b2fa17740f436","display_name":"Harvey Rayner","is_curated":true,"favorited_by_user":false,"favorites_aggregate":{"aggregate":{"count":4,"__typename":"favorites_aggregate_fields"},"__typename":"favorites_aggregate"},"profile":{"name":"Harvey Rayner","username":"patterndotco","bio":"Harvey is an English-born artist and creative coder currently based in Upstate NY, USA. He has a diverse background working as a designer, inventor, programmer and business owner while creating an extensive body of artwork spanning over 25 ye.....
```

but if i try to access the users key i get by doing `print(data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data']['users'])` or `print(data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data'][0]['users'])` i get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: `data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data']` is a string, so you're iterating over its characters. It looks like it's JSON, so you need to use `json.loads(data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data'])`

Comment: i mean i guess that worked but i still can't iterate over the rest - like if i try to get users from data['pageProps']['urqlState']['3369789927']['data']['users'], it gives me the same TypeError: string indices must be integers error

Comment: You can't do that because `['data']` is not a dictionary. You need to assign the result of `json.loads()` to another variable, then you can use `thatvariable['users']`